# Is there automatic formatting for an asp:literal control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to automatically format a `string` for literal insertion into JavaScript code?

Say you have this in your page:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    var strvar = <asp:Literal runat="server" id="ltrStrvar"></asp:Literal>;
</script>
```

And in your server-side code:

```csharp
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ltrStrvar.Text = "hello \"world\"";
}
```

Is there a way to *automatically* have it escape the string and surround it with quotes for error-free insertion into JavaScript, so all I have to do is set the `Text` property with an arbitrary string? I know how to do it *manually* but was looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom `LiteralWithQuotationMarks` user control which uses the `Literal` control internally and surrounds it with quotes if they're missing.

Comment: In addition to adding the quotes around it you would also need to escape all quotes with `\"`, and the same with single quotes and the escape character itself.

Comment: Yeah, the principal is sound but it should be more a "LiteralJSString" control. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
public string sanitizeJavascriptString(string dirtyInput)
{
    return dirtyInput.Replace("\\", "\\\\")
        .Replace("\"", "\\\"")
        .Replace("'","\\'");
}
```

I don't know if there is an existing escape function, but I doubt it.  I'm also not 100% sure what else needs to be escaped, but I assume you can add the other characters if you know what they are.

Comment: Will placing this method in my class *automatically* make it so I can set the `Text` property and have it escape?

Comment: @amphetamachine The point is that you would call this method on the string before setting the text property to do the escaping.  Defining the method and never using it obviously wouldn't do anything.

Comment: *Is there a way to automatically have it escape the string and surround it with quotes for error-free insertion into JavaScript, so all I have to do is set the Text property with an arbitrary string?* - OP

Comment: @amphetamachine Yes, I know you said that, and I'm saying this is likely the best you're going to get.  I don't see how calling this function would be such an extraordinary amount of work as to render it useless as a solution.  If you don't want to use it, then don't.